# Minimize browser window javascript

Tags: javascript

How can I minimize any browser window using a code (for example 'javascript') ?
I would like to minimize browser in infokiosk.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can't.

Comment: You could do this with http://www.breach.cc

Comment: I have an access only to the few pages in browser.

Comment: @jantimon Are you sure? "`Entirely written in Javascript.`" There's no JavaScript which could do what OP asks.

Comment: You can't minimize a window with javascript, but you can close it, and reopen it with a button that represents the 'minimized' window. If you need to save the state of the page, use a hash tag or Storage or even a cookie.

Comment: @teemu you could build a breech plugin which minimizes the browser using javascript